# empty response - Docker Container ASP.NET CORE 6

Tags: c#, .net, windows, docker

I got stuck on this for quite some time and i don't know why it doesn't work.

I looked into posts similair to mine but i can't fix it, (tried checking the firewall settings, using different ports).

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MonitorApplication1.dll"]
```

The application is a simple REST API with C# .NET Core 6. The database is a MS SQL Server Database.

The image and container seem fine but when i try to view it in the browser (using Chrome as standard, but also tried Edge) i get the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error.

The log of the container (using Docker Desktop) only shows this:
`{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}`

Update

I tried to create a new .NET 6 API with Docker Enabled but when i tried to run the container i still get the Error Empty Response.

Comment: HI, have you exposed ports? 
how do you run your docker?

Comment: Be aware that Swagger is disabled by default when running in a container

Comment: i tried to run it by using the cli and Docker desktop, both get the same results. the following message is written in the container log: **{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}**

Running it on 8080:8080 also tried 8085:8085

Comment: are you building from a fresh new application, or implemented a lot of logic already? suggest try a new application first.

Comment: this is a pretty small api, simple crud operations in 1 controller, 5 controllers that only are created for get/post.

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar problem by adding the [ASPNETCORE_URLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0) environment variable, like this:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the trick:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:80
```